# Mod function and select

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to sub select few accounts by comparing last digits of the day and last digits of account id , some reason I am getting a syntax error

```
Error 3706] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error: expected something between the 'select' keyword and the 'MOD' keyword.
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT TOP 10  acct.accoun_id  FROM accounts WHERE  current_date mod 10 =   select MOD 10(account_id)
```

Comment: `mod` is not an operator that works on dates in any database.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: If you really need to use mod then it should be select account_id MOD 10

Comment: sorry to disagree , select current_date mod 10, this query runs good and returns as desired result 9

Comment: Fix the 2nd MOD `where current_date mod 10 = account_id mod 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a very strange thing to do.  Assuming the `account_id` is a number and you want the day-of-the-month, then:

```
SELECT TOP 10  a.accoun_id
FROM accounts a
WHERE EXTRACT(day FROM CURRENT_DATE) MOD 10 = a.account_id MOD 10;
```